# Animation effects in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am doing an application in which a form data is filled by user.All are working fine.But I want the animation effects in Xamarin forms for android and iOS as shown below.Anyone please give me a suggestion to move forward with animation effects in my app.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: enter "xamarin forms animation" on google. that should get you started by reading documentation.

Comment: Please post your codes to show what you have achieved so far.

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods for animation on Forms.

like

```
Label lb = new Label();
lb.ScaleTo(...)
lb.FadeTo(...)
lb.TranslateTo(...)
```

and You can also adjust it's position by using lb.TranslateX or Y

You can use it and mix it when it's needed.
Then, You will achieve what you want.